# MAMP opening php file in browser (Mac OS X)

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I have correctly installed MAMP for my Mac Mini running Mac OS 10.10.1. I have used XAMPP before and opened a php file with it. Now I have two files I want to open called form.php and demo.php. I am going to open these with MAMP instead of XAMPP. I have them placed in MAMP > htdocs. Then I typed http://localhost:8888/form.php, and the page loaded, but nothing appeared, even though I have the code correctly entered and saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: The servers are working, and running.

Comment: Is a simple php script, a phpinfo for example, working?

Comment: I think it might be where I am placing the scripts and/or entering the directory.

Comment: @dlegall no, no matter how simple of a script it is it isn't working.

Comment: Isn't the PHP code appearing when you show source of your blank page?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in directory, it works fine with me

> Mac OS X users are advised to be careful when using TextEdit to edit
>   .php files, as it saves them in Rich Text Format, with an invisible
>   .rtf filename extension by default.

it might work if you use other HTML Editor

but if you have "Page not found", acknowledge me to change the answer.

Comment: I actually fixed it. I needed to make a new file in the correct directory.

Comment: create another .php file, and save it in same directory.

Comment: I know now that thats how to do it.